# Android multi-touch help

Tags: android, multi-touch

So, I'm developing an app and need to have two buttons pressed at the same time. 
I need the events for the buttons to be triggered when pressed(which is at the same time, too).

Imagine a car - I have left, right, forward and back. I need to press EG. forward and right together to make a right turn.

Here is my method but for some reason when I press both buttons, only the one pressed first is triggered... Any ideas?

```
    // Handle touches of the navigation arrows
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent theMotion) {
        switch (theMotion.getAction()) {
        // A button was PRESSED
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            switch (v.getId()) { // Which button?
            case R.id.freestyle_upArrow: // The upArrow
                bt.sendNXTcommand(MOTOR_B_FORWARD, 720);
                break;
            case R.id.freestyle_downArrow: // The downArrow
                bt.sendNXTcommand(MOTOR_B_BACKWARD, 720);
                break;
            case R.id.freestyle_leftArrow: // The leftArrow
                bt.sendNXTcommand(MOTOR_A_LEFT, 720);
                break;
            case R.id.freestyle_rightArrow: // The rightArrow
                bt.sendNXTcommand(MOTOR_A_RIGHT, 720);
                break;
            }
            break;
        // A button was RELEASED
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            switch (v.getId()) { // Which button?
            case R.id.freestyle_upArrow: // The upArrow
                bt.sendNXTcommand(MOTOR_B_STOP, 0);
                break;
            case R.id.freestyle_downArrow: // The downArrow
                bt.sendNXTcommand(MOTOR_B_STOP, 0);
                break;
            case R.id.freestyle_leftArrow: // The leftArrow
                break;
            case R.id.freestyle_rightArrow: // The rightArrow
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

So, any have any ideas? Does it have something to do with the number of points allowed on my screen?

PHONE SPECS: **Samsung Galaxy Ace running Android OS on firmware 2.2.1**

Regards,

Rich.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
```

You want to look for

```
MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP
MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
```

For the second finger. Keep in mind you will get a ACTION_POINTER_UP no matter which finger is lifted first

Answer (score -1):

for that you have check whether **ACTION_DOWN**(single touch) and **ACTION_POINTER_DOWN**(Multi touch) based on that create your logic. note: **ACTION_POINTER** means multitouch itself